# ANR: com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule

Tags: android, multithreading, react-native, android-anr-dialog

Recently we have started getting ANR specifically on android 7/ 7.1 / 7.1.1.
The stacktrace goes like this

```
Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Waiting

at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule (ModuleHolder.java:14)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.getModule (NativeModuleRegistry.java:11)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:5)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
  at com.facebook.internal.instrument.InstrumentUtility.getUIManager (InstrumentUtility.java:4)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance (ReactInstanceManager.java:4)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.attachToReactInstanceManager (ReactRootView.java:12)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication (ReactRootView.java:9)
  at com.myapp.ReactActivity.onCreate (ReactActivity.java:191)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6845)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2700)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2808)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1541)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:165)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6375)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:912)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:802)

"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Native (still starting up)
  #00  pc 000000000001c0ac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #00  pc 00000000000e6dd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+160)
  #00  pc 0000000000463cc4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*)+252)
  #00  pc 0000000000463180  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+124)
  #00  pc 0000000000462ab0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+116)
  #00  pc 0000000000068440  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+196)
  #00  pc 000000000001dd70  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)

"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 Blocked

  #00  pc 000000000001beec  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #00  pc 00000000000e8148  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+160)
  #00  pc 0000000000240ee8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::GetTask(art::Thread*)+360)
  #00  pc 00000000002417c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+92)
  #00  pc 00000000001e5530  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+124)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks (Native method)
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run (Daemons.java:435)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:760)


....Many more thread in WAITING state
```

**Output of react-native info**

> System:
> OS: macOS 11.4
> CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @2.60GHz
> Memory: 115.29 MB / 16.00 GB
> Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh Binaries:
> Node: 14.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/node
> Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
> npm: 6.14.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/npm
> Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
> SDKs: iOS SDK: Platforms: DriverKit 21.0.1, iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchO 8.0
> IDEs:
> Xcode: 13.1/13A1030d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
> npmPackages:
> react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
>
> react-native: 0.61.4 => 0.61.4
> npmGlobalPackages:
> react-native-cli: 2.0.1

**Steps to reproduce**
Unable to reproduce but from what I understand. This happens sometimes only on android 7. When calling
`rootView.startReactApplication(...)`
We have two different React Instance manager initialised using `createReactContextInBackground()` on Application onCreate for two different features. Second one was introduced in this new release.